# Xpages chained djFilteringSelect in separate dialogs

Tags: dialog, dojo, xpages

I am trying to make a 2nd djFilteringSelect using a @Dbcolumn depending on the value selected in the 1st djFilteringSelect control. That's a common task, using a partial refresh. However, each of the controls is within a dialog control from the extension library. One dialog pops up, the user selects a value, and automatically the 1st dialog closes and the 2nd opens. YOU CAN'T SEEM TO REFRESH THE FIELD (I'm guessing b/c it's not in the DOM). I've tried writing the first value to to an computed field and/or a text box on the main Xpage using CSJS and then looking for that value for the second lookup. Also, tried with SSJS, etc. I tried do updates and writing to fields on either the onChange or on the click of button. How do I go about using the selected value of the first to do the lookup in the 2nd?

Comment: Have you tried using a single dialog control where you hide and show the relevant controls? I am using this approach in several apps.

Comment: Yes! That is the solution.

Comment: I will add my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single dialog control where you hide and show the relevant controls. I am using this approach in several apps.